# Is there a REST API for Google App Engine search?

Tags: google-app-engine

I looked online at the documentation, but didn't see any mention of a REST API for search in Google App Engine's standard environment.  The reason I ask is that I would like to migrate off of the standard environment into the flexible environment, but the GAE Search API is not offered there in Python (or any other language) AFAIK.  Thus asking if there is a REST API available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at this time no REST API for Google App Engine's Search API, it is only available for Java, Python and Go in the standard environment.

What you can do is separate the part of your application that calls the search API from the rest of your application and deploy it as a separate service that runs on the Standard environment, while the rest of your application is deployed as one or many services in the Flexible environment.

If that's what you want to do, you can get started by reading about [Microservices Architecture on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) and [when to use the flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#when_to_use_the_flexible_environment).